# What are the eigenvalues of the 8 point DFT matrix?

Tags: dft, eigendecomposition

I  know that the eigenvalues for 4 point DFT matrix can be found from $F_4^4=I$. Is this also valid for 8, 16 and higher orders? For example with  8 points, will it be $F_8^8=I$ ? If not, how  can I can compute them?

Comment: dont crosspost without mentioning it! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099822/what-is-the-eigenvalues-of-8-point-dft-matrix From $F^4=I$ it directly follows that $F^8=I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues belong to the same set of quartic roots of unity verifying $\lambda^4=1$, whatever the order of the DFT.

For more details on their multiplicity, you can read: 
[Eigenvectors and Functions of the Discrete Fourier Transform](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1163843/), 1982, Dickinson and Steiglitz ([online](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.434.5279&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).